# Overwrite file from old folder to new folder

Tags: mv

I have 2 folder: 
- /Desktop/old
- /Desktop/new

In old folder, I have following file:
- olda.txt
- oldb.txt

In new folder, I have following file:
- newa.txt
- newb.txt
- newc.txt

And I want to overwrite the file from old to new. And I tried like this:

```
 mv /home/user/Desktop/old /home/user/Desktop/new
```

I get the below output in new folder:
- old
- newa.txt
- newb.txt
- newc.txt

What I want is like this:
- olda.txt (from old/olda.txt)
- oldb.txt (from old/oldb.txt)
- newc.txt

How should I write in order to get it?

Comment: Your requirement is a bit weird. Can you specify it further? For example, we are told that `new/newa.txt` should be renamed to `old/olda.txt`, but what about `new/olda.txt`, or `new/some_other_filename`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just moved the folder itself inside the new folder. Just use:

```
mv /home/user/Desktop/old/* /home/user/Desktop/new
```

Comment: The OP wants to rename files in addition to moving them. For example, `new/newa.txt` has to become `old/olda.txt`.

Comment: Downvoted! OP Wants to overwrite the `newa.txt` and `newb.txt` with `olda.txt` and `oldb.txt`.

Comment: @WitchDoctor I misunderstood, but according to the comments: Why do you know that the OP wants to rename the files?

Comment: @chaos You solved my problems.

Comment: @WitchDoctor Also, your comment suggests exactly the same... =)

Comment: @MichaelKuan You should mark this answer as accepted if it answers your question. Otherwise, the rest of us won't know that the problem has been solved until after we've read the question, answer and all the comments.

Comment: @chaos : Yeah. I misunderstood that. I deleted my comment :) . But now,it looks the OP was expecting the same but he has to update his question properly.The output he showed in his question is not correct!